# The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1, could not pass id properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some issues with my Angular application.

Shortly explained, I create an object of type `FormInput`, which is storing all the data from a form. After clicking a button I want to perform two actions:

1. save the `FormInput` object and
2. navigate to a new page with the id of the object I have just created.

My code saves the object, but when I call my function for navigation to another page, the id I have passed is `undefined`. I do not how to properly get the id from the currently created object and pass it to the function for navigating.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  forminput: Forminput = new Forminput();
  shops: Array<Shop> = [];
  products: Array<Product> = [];
  shop: Shop;
  product: Product;
  exampleForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private formService: FormService, private router: Router){}

  get f() { return this.exampleForm.controls; }
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.exampleForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.submitted)
    {
      this.save();
    }
    this.goToDocument(this.forminput.id);    // here it is undefined 
  }

  save() {
    this.forminput.shopid = this.shop.id;
    this.forminput.productid = this.product.id;
    this.formService.createInputForm(this.forminput)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        },
            error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      secondName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      familyName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      shop: ['', [Validators.required]],
      products: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.getShops();
  }

  fireGetShopProducts(){
    console.log(this.shop.id);
    this.getShopProducts(this.shop.id);
  }

  getShopProducts(id: number){
    this.formService.getShopProducts(id)
      .subscribe(
        (product: Array<Product>) => {
          console.log(product);
          this.products = product;
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  getShops(){
    this.formService.getListShops()
      .subscribe(
        (shops: Array<Shop>) => {
          console.log(shops);
          this.shops = shops;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  goToDocument(id: number){
    this.router.navigate(['document', id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the id contained in `data` on your `formService.createInputForm().subscribe` call? The value you are logging out?

Comment: Yes, it is contained there. This call formService.createInputForm().subscribe is returning InputForm object, which is defined by id, firstname, secondname and etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where you assign **id** to **this.forminput** ?
2. Looks like you should **goToDocument()** if **this.submitted** = **true** so put this line inside **if**, below **save()**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I solve the problem. I just make the call inside save() function and it started working fine:

```
  save() {
    this.forminput.shopid = this.shop.id;
    this.forminput.productid = this.product.id;
    this.formService.createInputForm(this.forminput)
      .subscribe((data: Forminput) => {
        this.id = data.id;
        this.goToDocument(this.id);
        },
            error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

However, it is yet a bit strange, because if cut the line   `this.goToDocument(this.id);` from save() an put it inside onSubmit() after calling save() it stop working.

Comment: save function only make a call -but don't wait until finished- (it's called make an async call) this is the reason because you need put the actions into "subscribe function"

Comment: Thank you for this answer!!! I will read more details about this!